# How can batch file accept arguments for Java?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, command-line

I'm trying to write a batch file (`run.bat`) that can be invoked something like this:

```
run.bat "whatever.log"
```

But under the hood, the batch file is passing the argument (`"whatever.log"`) to the following command:

```
java -cp "fizz.jar;a.jar;b.jar;c.jar;d.jar" com.myapp.FizzDriver "whatever.log"
```

Again, if you run: `run.bat "blah.txt"`, then that batch file would execute:

```
java -cp "fizz.jar;a.jar;b.jar;c.jar;d.jar" com.myapp.FizzDriver "blah.txt"
```

My best attempt at `run.bat` so far is:

```
@ECHO OFF
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java java -cp "fizz.jar;a.jar;b.jar;c.jar;d.jar" com.myapp.FizzDriver ???
```

But I'm not sure how to parameterize the argument (???). I'm also not sure if the batch file is missing anything or is incorrect with the way I've written it. Ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to put %1, but you have another issue. When you use 'java -jar', the '-cp' argument is ignored: the CLASSPATH is taken from the jar manifest only.

Comment: Thanks @EJP - what if I made my Java command-line: `java -cp "fizz.jar;a.jar;b.jar;c.jar;d.jar" com.myapp.FizzDriver %1`? (Where `FizzDriver` is the main class inside `fizz.jar`). **Would that fix the batch file?** Thanks again!

Comment: That would fix the classpath problem, but it's a retrograde step. You should specify both the `Class-path` and the `Main-class` in the JAR manifest. Complete encapsulation that way. All the batch file should do is run the JAR file and pass the argument()s. If you can have more than one argument, specify `%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9`.

Answer (score 2):

To pass one command line parameter, use `%1`. If you need to pass more than one, you can either use `%1 %2` etc, or use `%*` to pass all of them at once.